# Replace word outside regex

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to make a replacement in an inverted way, where the regular expression is maintained and the other characters are eliminated?

**Word**
`String word = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 27/08/2020 consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam consequat nisi est.";`

**Regex**

```
([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})
```

`word.replaceAll("([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})","");`

**Expected**

```
27/08/2020
```

Comment: Do you mean something like this?
https://regex101.com/r/GR6B8f/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's called `find()`.

```java
String word = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 27/08/2020 consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam consequat nisi est.";

Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4})").matcher(word);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

*Output*

```
27/08/2020
```

---

Alternative, make the regex match everything, and use the capture group you already defined:

```java
word.replaceFirst(".*?([0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{4}).*", "$1")
```

*Result*

```java
27/08/2020
```

---

The main difference between the two if what happens of the regex doesn't match, i.e. if the string doesn't have a date in it.

The first will print nothing. You can explicitly control how you handle it by writing an `else` clause.

The second will result in the full original string, unchanged. You cannot control how you handle the "not found" condition.

Comment: And if there are two possible outcomes and the one required is the second one? `String word = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 27/08/2020 consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam consequat 29/08/2020 nisi est.";`, I know there is such a thing as groups, can you handle that?

Comment: If you want it to match the last instead of the first occurrence, change `if` to `while` and only print the last value (first option), or change the leading `.*?` to `.*` (second option).